# Strobe Media Playback and RSS playlists?

Tags: video, rss, video-player

OSMF [defines](http://osmf.org/dev/osmf/specpdfs/SyndicationSupport.pdf) RSS support and I'm wondering whether Strobe Media Playback (SMP) supports that, maybe by providing a plugin or the like? I wasn't able to find any example describing this.

There is .m3u playlist support as described in [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/dxb277/blogs/squeezeTheMoment/2010/12/possibilities-are-many-with-strobe.html), but that doesn't really help our use case.

Interestingly, there is a SMIL plugin which can be used for playlists too. SMIL being way less popular than RSS, I would have expected support for RSS should be available.

Does support for (media) RSS exist in SMP?